# DRY solution for multiple connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have multiple connections that connect to external servers via socket. However on each will do actually same thing. What is DRY solution to this?

For example:

`ami1`, `ami2`, `ami3` are connected to 3 servers.

```
var ami1 = new require('asterisk-manager')('port','host1','username','password', true);
var ami2 = new require('asterisk-manager')('port','host2','username','password', true);
var ami3 = new require('asterisk-manager')('port','host3','username','password', true);
```

I have to repeat for each one

```
ami1.keepConnected();
ami2.keepConnected();
ami3.keepConnected();
```

Every each one will do actually same thing.

```
ami1.on('response', function(evt) {
 if () { }
 if () { }
 if () { }
});


ami2.on('response', function(evt) {
 if () { }
 if () { }
 if () { }
});

ami3.on('response', function(evt) {
 if () { }
 if () { }
 if () { }
});
```

Comment: You can create an array of objects holding creds for each service and then iterate through this array, create a service, call keepConnected and add a callback func

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the connections in an array:

```
var ami = [
  new require('asterisk-manager')('port','host1','username','password', true),
  new require('asterisk-manager')('port','host2','username','password', true),
  new require('asterisk-manager')('port','host3','username','password', true)
];
```

Us a loop to keep them alive

```
for(var i=0;i<ami.length;i++)
    ami[i].keepConnected();
```

(You could wrap that in a function `keepAllConnected` if you make multiple calls to it)

And bind events the same way

```
for(var i=0;i<ami.length;i++){
 ami[i].on('response', function(evt) {
   if () { }
   if () { }
   if () { }
  });
}
```